# Perform Operations on date fetched by mysql database in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="afif123", db="library")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
date_query = '''SELECT Date from issued_book '''
mycursor.execute(date_query)
date_fetch = mycursor.fetchall()
date1 = date_fetch[0]
print(date1)
today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(today)
diff = today - date1
print(diff)
```

i am getting error like this

(datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 15, 47, 51),)

Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-20 17:38:41

File "C:/Users/Desktop/lib/d.py", line 12, in 
diff = today - date1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'tuple'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Do you get errors or incorrect output?

Comment: after fetching date from database i m getting this (datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 15, 47, 51),) now i have to convert it in this 2019-04-20 00:25:19 but how?

Comment: Why do you have to convert it? You get datetime.datetime from database, now you can do `today - date1` if today is datetime.datetime.

Comment: date(today) - date(date1) can u try like this ? it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so this helped me

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="afif123", db="library")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
date_query = '''SELECT Date from issued_book '''
mycursor.execute(date_query)
date_fetch = mycursor.fetchall()
date1 = date_fetch[0]
print("date1:", date1)
d1 = date1[0]
print("a1:", d1)
today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(today, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print("today:", today)
diff = t1 - d1
print("diff:", diff)
```

OUTPUT
date1: (datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 15, 47, 51),)

a1: 2019-04-18 15:47:51

today: 2019-04-21 12:00:47

diff: 2 days, 20:12:56

Answer (score 0):

Finding difference between two dates is just a matter of subtracting the two datetime objects, for example

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 15, 47, 51)
date2 = datetime.datetime.now()

print(date2-date1)
#1 day, 20:58:11.972530
```

Comment: i am getting date like this (datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 15, 47, 51),) and after subtracting it with current date the ui(pyqt) stops

Comment: That means something  is wrong in how you are operating on dates. Remove the UI part and just run the code which processes the date, so as to isolate the issue

Comment: (datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 15, 47, 51),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-20 17:38:41                                                                                                                            
  File "C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/lib/d.py", line 12, in <module>
    diff = today - date1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'tuple'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Make sure today and date1, both have the same datatype, datetime.datetime

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it helped you @AfifShaikh :)